# How can I get my virtual directory in IIS to work. (Can't read web.config file)

Tags: iis

I created a virtual directory to a network share. Both the virtual directory and the network share have Everyone Full Control permissions. The directory is full of zip files to be downloaded from the website. In IIS Manager, I can view the contents of the remote directory.[image]

When I try to download a file using http://localhost:8081/FMFiles/SS2%20Missions/Ancient.zip, I see this server error:

[image]

In the thiefFanMissions folder, I see the web.config file.

[image]

and its contents are thus:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
          <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Just because your admin user can see the remote share, does not mean the user-account running the ApplicationPool `W3wp.exe` can also. That account is usually a limited local service account with no access to any network shares. You need to do some research about how allow IIS to access a network share.